# How to show the following conditional expectation relation holds for a Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion

Suppose that $B_k$ stands for a standard Brownian motion process.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{S}B_k dk\, -uB_T}\Big| B_t = x\Big)
\end{equation}
where $w$ and $u$ are constants, and $t< T < S$. Then, using the tower property of the conditional expectation, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{S}B_k dk\, -uB_T}\Big| B_t = x\Big) = \mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{S}B_k dk\, -uB_T}\Big|B_T\Big)\Big| B_t = x\Big) = \mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{T}B_k dk\, -w\int_{T}^{S}B_k dk\, -uB_T}\Big|B_T\Big)\Big| B_t = x\Big) = \mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{T}B_k dk\, - uB_T}\mathbb{E}\Big( e^{-w\int_{T}^{S}B_k dk}\Big|B_T\Big)\Big| B_t = x\Big)
\end{equation}
My question here is that in the last equation, why we can take this expression $e^{-w\int_{t}^{T}B_k dk}$ out of the inner expectation operator given $B_T$.

Comment: Is $B_{T}$ the sigma algebra generated by only $B_{T}$ or generated by $B_{k}, t \leq k \leq T$? I think it has to be the one generated by $B_{k}, t \leq k \leq T$, otherwise you could not argue with the tower property. Then, in my opinion, the answer to your question is that since $-w \int_{t}^{T}B_{k}dk$ is measurable wrt to sigma algebra generated by  $B_{k}, t \leq k \leq T$ and $exp(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ and measurability still holds under continuous transformations, you can use the property of conditional expectation that allows you to pull out measurable parts.

Comment: I do not know exactly. So, you mean the sigma-algebra is a natural filtration generated by $B_T$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: Could you please let me know if we replace $B_t$ with $r_t$, where $r_t$ is following a CIR model (interest rate), then we can say the same thing.

Comment: I mean, in the above formula we write $r_t$, instead of $B_t$

Comment: To make it clear, I have written another version:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{-w\int_{t}^{S}r_k dk\, -ur_T}\Big| r_t = x\Big)
\end{equation}

Comment: Peter, Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I would be glad to have your opinion on my last question as well.

Comment: I believe you can use the same line of reasoning here.

Comment: I appreciate your time and kind consideration. Only one thing. From a technical perspective, it may be more appropriate to say that $-w\int_{t}^{T}B_k dk$ is adapted to the natural filtration generated by $B_T$, because measurability is applicable for random variables while $-w\int_{t}^{T}B_k dk$ is a stochastic process itself.

Comment: That is correct. I should have explained it using adaptedness.

Comment: Thanks and have a good day bro.